# winnower template bibliography citation

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I want to change the format of citing the bibliography in winnower template.

[image]

As you see above, when I write `\cite{Author2Year2}`, I get this:

[image]

I wonder if I could get `[1]` or `[2]` instead of `Du and Zhan 2003`.

This is how I added the information of bibliography.

[image]

And this is how I get the winnower template:
[winnower template](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/winnower#.Vcewxp1Viko)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers}{natbib}
```

just before

```
\documentclass{winnower}
```

so to tell `natbib` that you want numeric citations instead of author-year ones.

This is the output of the Overleaf template:

[image]

Comment: @EunjinCho You're welcome.